# Load properties file based on language Properties Placeholder

Tags: java, spring, properties

```
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="locations">
    <value>classpath*:app.properties</value>
```

Loading single properties file works fine, but now I need to load `app_en.properties` and `app_fr.properties` file based on the language provided as request(payload) input. How to configure this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use List tag for this

```
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath*:app.properties</value>
        <value>classpath*:app_en.properties</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: how to get messages from app.properties and app_en.properties based on language

Comment: Go through this http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.in/2009/02/tips-regarding-springs.html. read priority and setting the order section..